# Kitematic - Force using Virtualbox

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox, kitematic

At this moment Docker is not work properly for my copy of Windows 10 (latest version), but It's not problem right now. I just want to force Kitematic to USE VIRTUALBOX as default. Is there any way to do that?
[image]

Comment: click use virtualbox, it will work fine.

Comment: No it's not fine. Even if it will work, you're losing literally minutes...

Answer (score 1):

Using procmon I was able to find the settings folder used by Kitematic: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Kinematic\`. Deleting this folder and restarting Kitematic worked for me.

You may also want to edit the Docker settings at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json`, and set `UseWindowsContainers` as appropriate.

Hope this helps!

[image: Docker settings.json]